# How do I ensure the format for saving and parsing string representations of Objects correlate properly

Tags: java, regex, format

I am making a small boardgame program which needs to persist the state of the board to a file, and later read from the file and re-create the board.

I am delegating this functionality to the class shown below. I would like to implement this such that the save format of a square of the board along with it's co-ordinates are captured in the SQUARE_FORMAT constant, and the regex for reading that same information is captured in the LOAD_REGEX constant.  Both should co-relate in code and also be able to visually decipher (by that I mean that a person should be able to clearly see that they co-relate to the same data)

Is there an idiom or pattern for doing this in Java code ?

```
public class BoardPersistenceUtility {

    private final String SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT = "";
    private fial String LOAD_REGEX = "";

    public void save(PrintWriter writer, Board board) {

    }

    public Board load(BufferedReader reader) {
        // Implement
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

On reading my question again, I guess it might be a bit confusing, about what exactly I am looking for. I am specifically looking for the right way to represent SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT so that it clearly co-relates with the regex LOAD_REGEX.

SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT would ideally be a String which uses special characters/variables that will be replaced with actual values and the result will be saved to a file. LOAD_REGEX is the corresponding regex that will be used to read contents from the file. The regex will use capturing groups so I can re-create the original object from the values I get from the capturing groups.

My question is, what are the idioms around creating such pairs of Strings - one of them a format string to be used for saving data, and the other a regex to be used while reading that data.

**Update 2:**

On thinking a bit more, I think I have been able to clarify my question a bit better.

If you look at both the Strings, SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT is a format string which will be used in String.format() to create the text for a square on the board, which will be saved in the file. The constant SQUARE_LOAD_REGEX is a regex which will be used to read the line and capture relevant parts into named groups, so I can re-create the original object. (sorry if my regex is slightly incorrect... I quickly wrote something, but I need to refresh some regex principles to ensure that this is indeed what I need)

If you look at both these Strings visually, it is difficult to co-relate them together. Perhaps it is because we do not have any named variables in a Java format String. The best we can do is to specify %i where i is the index of the argument.

I would like to understand if there is any idiom or pattern to represent such pairs of Strings, where one is used for formatting some data to text and the other is used to read the same text and parse it's parts.

```
public class BoardPersistenceUtility {

    private final String SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT = 
                  "%d,%d:%b-%s";
    private final String SQUARE_LOAD_REGEX = 
                  "^(?<row>\d*),(?<col>\d*):(?<mine>true|false)-(?<status>\w)$";

    public void save(PrintWriter writer, Board board) {

    }

    public Board load(BufferedReader reader) {
        // Implement
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you don't want to use normal Java serialization?

Comment: Java idiom for doing what, exactly? There's no relationship between two string instance variables other than what you provide through comments, naming conventions, and usage.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes I would prefer to save them in a simple text file

Comment: @DaveNewton Sure I agree that we will have to add a comment to relate the two together... what I am looking for is how would I represent the format string so that it clearly (visually) co-related with the regex .... is there a standard way of doing this ?

Comment: @Parag ... No? Because I still don't know what you mean, because we don't have much information to go on. Moved rest of comment to answer because it's too long. Which is, in fact, what she said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you mean, but need formatting, so answer instead of comment.

First of all, the names are almost completely unrelated--related them somehow.

```
SQUARE_DATA_STORE
SQUARE_DATA_REGEX
```

Second, there's no point in differentiating the "style" of the saved data if there's only a single `BoardPersistenceUtility`--if there were multiple formats then that information would be captured in a persistence utility subclass, like `SquareFormatPersister` or something.

Third, according to your text, one string is where the data will actually be stored. The other is a regular expression. The two will, in this case, *never* be "visually similar"--regular expressions of any complexity will never (much) look like the strings they can represent. (In this case, we have no clue, because we don't know what the board data can look like, of course.)

If your code is so non-self-explanatory that the reader can't figure out the two fields are related through via your comments and your code, something has gone horribly wrong. I'm having a hard time imagining this code is so overwhelmingly complex that their relationship cannot be trivially communicated.

---

*Edit after update*

The answer is still no.

You could use a templating mechanism to provide names for the fields, similar to those used in your regex. This might also make the code a bit more self-explanatory as you'd fill the template context with named values (like "row" or "col").

You could use a real parser/generator, but the complexity there is a bit too much.

You could use a DSL (internal using Groovy, JRuby, JavaScript, etc. or external, which brings us back to parsing) and write chunks of the code that way.

IMO you're over-thinking, and over-estimating perceived complexity: except *possibly* for the templating solution, which IMO is likely over-engineering for the level of difficulty, you'd be far better off writing one or two sentences, which should be more than enough to relate the "fields" of the load and save formats.

Comment: Please see update 2. I have proposed a solution and also explain why I think it could be better. Thanks for being patient :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess putting comments in code, is probably the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Note: you call `SQUARE_SAVE_FORMAT` and `LOAD_REGEX` "constants" which they are not, as you haven't declared them `static final`. It's better to keep terminology clear :-)

The simplest way to link these two is to define a class which encloses both as (final) fields. If you plan to define multiple such pairs of information, you can define multiple instances of the class, one for each type of format.

If you really want to keep these as constants, it may be best to define the enclosing class as an `enum`. Note that Java `enum`s may contain methods too, so you may choose to implement the save/load logic as [Strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in the enum instances themselves, and call these polymorphically, which may help simplify your code.

Comment: You are right... sorry about the confusion about them not being final :-)

Comment: Sorry but I may not have worded my question properly. I have updated it to better specify the intent

Answer (score 1):

Put comments in your code to explain that they're related, how they're related, what they're used for, and that if one is changed, the other should be modified accordingly.

Implement a unit test to make sure that a saved board can be loaded.

Make sure that your build and release process runs the unit tests, and fails if one of them doesn't pass.